# If there is empty date column then input current date and time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

If the date column is empty I want to input the current date and time using Oracle SQL.

Given table,

| Login_Time | Logout_Time |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-20 09:57:00 | 2021-08-20 10:30:00 |
| 2021-08-20 10:00:00 |  |
| 2021-08-20 08:00:00 |  |

In the Logout Time column is null then I have to input current time and date.

So I have written the below query,

```
SELECT "login_time", 
       CASE WHEN "logout_time" IS NULL THEN sysdate ELSE "logout_time" END AS "logout_time"
  FROM abc
```

I am not able to enter current time using above query. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Please explain, what do you mean by "I cannot enter current time"? `sysdate` returns `date` datatype which contains year, month, day of month, hours, minutes and seconds. Always

Comment: there's no problem with the current case except getting rid of quotes wrapping column names. Moreover the quotes are not needed for the alias(`"logout_time"`). Using `NVL2(logout_time,logout_time,sysdate) AS logout_time` might be an alternative shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that both columns are `date` and you are using `sysdate` with the default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`( so that you are not altering it before running the query )

Let's try it with a demo

```
SQL> create table test_date ( logon_time date , logout_time date ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into test_date values ( sysdate-1/4 , sysdate ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test_date values ( sysdate-1/4 , sysdate ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test_date values ( sysdate-1/4 , sysdate ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from test_date ;

LOGON_TIM LOGOUT_TI
--------- ---------
20-AUG-21 20-AUG-21
20-AUG-21 20-AUG-21
20-AUG-21 20-AUG-21
```

Oracle stores date columns as packets, but you can show those values in any format you want, as long as it is a valid date format. By default, the database will show it according to default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, which you can find in the view NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS.

```
SQL> select parameter,value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_DATE_FORMAT' ;

PARAMETER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT
DD-MON-RR
```

But we can modify this by several ways. One of them is altering the session level

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ;

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test_date ;

LOGON_TIME          LOGOUT_TIME
------------------- -------------------
20.08.2021 03:54:03 20.08.2021 09:54:03
20.08.2021 03:54:10 20.08.2021 09:54:10
20.08.2021 03:54:14 20.08.2021 09:54:14

SQL> insert into test_date values ( sysdate-1/8 , null ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test_date ;

LOGON_TIME          LOGOUT_TIME
------------------- -------------------
20.08.2021 03:54:03 20.08.2021 09:54:03
20.08.2021 03:54:10 20.08.2021 09:54:10
20.08.2021 03:54:14 20.08.2021 09:54:14
20.08.2021 06:55:15

SQL> select logon_time , case when logout_time is null then sysdate else logout_time end as logout_time from test_date ;

LOGON_TIME          LOGOUT_TIME
------------------- -------------------
20.08.2021 03:54:03 20.08.2021 09:54:03
20.08.2021 03:54:10 20.08.2021 09:54:10
20.08.2021 03:54:14 20.08.2021 09:54:14
20.08.2021 06:55:15 20.08.2021 09:55:46
```

Comment: @unanoymous, does this answer solve your issue ? If so, please accept the answer. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understood the problem.

You said that you aren't

> able to **enter** current time using above query (`select "login_time", case when ...`)

Well, of course you aren't. If "enter" means that you should "update" the table, then you should have used `UPDATE`, not `SELECT`.

Current table contents:

```
SQL> select * from test;

LOGIN_TIME          LOGOUT_TIME
------------------- -------------------
2021-08-20 09:57:00 2021-08-20 10:30:00
2021-08-20 10:00:00
2021-08-20 08:00:00
```

Update NULL values (for only 2 rows in sample table):

```
SQL> update test set logout_time = sysdate
  2  where logout_time is null;

2 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

LOGIN_TIME          LOGOUT_TIME
------------------- -------------------
2021-08-20 09:57:00 2021-08-20 10:30:00
2021-08-20 10:00:00 2021-08-20 18:55:55
2021-08-20 08:00:00 2021-08-20 18:55:55

SQL>
```

---

For future inserts, set column's **default value** so that Oracle inserts it if `logout_time` doesn't exist:

```
SQL> alter table test modify logout_time default sysdate;

Table altered.

SQL> insert into test (login_time) values (date '2021-01-23');  --> no logout time here

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

LOGIN_TIME          LOGOUT_TIME
------------------- -------------------
2021-08-20 09:57:00 2021-08-20 10:30:00
2021-08-20 10:00:00 2021-08-20 18:58:15
2021-08-20 08:00:00 2021-08-20 18:58:15
2021-01-23 00:00:00 2021-08-20 18:58:44   --> logout time is automatically inserted

SQL>
```